# how can i fix ssh timeout?

Tags: cluster-computing, redhat, condor

all
The cluster system is constructed using the Perceus program. (scientific linuxs 6.9)
I installed condor in the vnfs file.
After this, when I make an ssh connection, I get a problem that ssh connection is disconnected after 10 minutes. The command is not recognized as shown below.
ssh was not disconnected before installing condor. However, we confirmed that pinging is done without loss.
how could fix this problem? Please suggest a solution
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XrkNn.png)

Answer (score 0):

Can you go to this directory to edit ssh file

cd /etc/ssh/sshd_config

change 
ClientAliveInterval 120
ClientAliveCountMax 720

This will make the server send the clients a “null packet” every 120 seconds and not disconnect them until the client have been inactive for 720 intervals (120 seconds * 720 = 86400 seconds = 24 hours).