# cd: /etc/ssh/sshd_config: Not a directory error while fixing ssh timeout issue

Tags: unix, terminal, centos, digital-ocean, centos8

I have created a droplet on Digital Ocean and installed CentOS as its OS. I would like to resolve the **frequent timeout** of the remote ssh connection. I found a guide on this link [how can i fix ssh timeout?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49510849/how-can-i-fix-ssh-timeout/49782490#49782490) . I have successfully navigated to **/etc/ssh/** directory. When I list available sub-directories in **/etc/ssh/** directory, I am able to see **sshd_config sub-directory**. However, when I try moving into the sub-directory I get the error "bash: cd: /etc/ssh/sshd_config: Not a directory."
What could I be doing wrong?

Below is what I've keyed in the terminal

```html
[root@centosFirstServer134327 ssh]# pwd
/etc/ssh

[root@centosFirstServer134327 ssh]# ls
moduli        ssh_host_ecdsa_key      ssh_host_ed25519_key.pub  sshd_config
ssh_config    ssh_host_ecdsa_key.pub  ssh_host_rsa_key
ssh_config.d  ssh_host_ed25519_key    ssh_host_rsa_key.pub

[root@centosFirstServer134327 ssh]# cd /etc/ssh

[root@centosFirstServer134327 ssh]# cd /etc/ssh/sshd_config
bash: cd: /etc/ssh/sshd_config: Not a directory
```

Comment: That's because `sshd_config` is a file.  The naming convention used is that the `.d` indicates a directory.  A `ls -l` would show you that also.

Comment: But what's the question you have and would like to get an answer for?

Comment: @stdunbar thanks for the response, I've been able to open the file. I was trying to cd into it thinking it is a folder. Thanks a lot!!

Comment: @ArkadiuszDrabczyk I was trying to cd into the ssh_config file thinking it is a directory yet it is a file, stdunbar helped me solve the issue

Answer (score 0):

`sshd_config` is a file. This is why you are unable to `cd` to it.

Comment: Thank you for the response, now I have known that ssh_config is a file and not a directory.